# New Android Studio don't let me build project with API 23

Tags: android, android-studio

Today, I upgraded latest Android Studio latest Version and build the project. And the problem is New Android Studio don't let me compile project with SDK 23...
I cannot build with SDK 25 because it is crush on lower SDK version and only work with some upper SDK. Please suggest how could I solve this problem.

Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

Here is my gradle code,

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.androidlivetv"

        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id: "90582504-49da-44c1-8a3c-800ca73877af",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "267076126070"]

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:2.+@aar'
        compile 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:2.5.5'
        compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.8'
        compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    }
```

Comment: You can always compile with the latest SDK and run on lesser API versions.  Please describe the errors when you try that and **after** you update the support dependencies to **match** the `compileSdk` version number

Answer (score 0):

Just change the target sdk to 23 and compile with 25 it shouldn't crash..

Comment: Here log output... 
Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-26 20:39:10.835 3158-3158/com.app.androidlivetv E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-26 20:39:10.845 3158-3158/com.app.androidlivetv D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-26 20:39:10.845 3158-3158/com.app.androidlivetv W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6541908)
03-26 20:39:10.855 3158-3158/com.app.androidlivetv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: maybe your'e using a code newer then your target sdk somewhere in you'r project?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set in you gradle
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
And you have to upgrade build tools version as well.
Sample that should compile for min version 23 (

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Comment: If I set to minSDKversion to 23, how would lower SDK version use my app?